# Using custom image as background of Navigation bar of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to use an image as the background for my navigation bar. I can get the image into the bar, but it doesn't appear properly. I have attached an image of the desired background, and the result that I am getting.

In addition this is the code I am using to get the image into the bar background.

```
navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"Top Bar Slice"), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

EDIT:
One of the answers got the image into the code, but now it is tile-ing across the bar. Is there a way to fix this?

I am now using this code in the app delegate:

UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Top Bar"), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)

Comment: Image I want to use as the background
http://i.stack.imgur.com/b7w4m.png

Result using the mentioned code
http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7p2i.png

Comment: The size of the image is 640x90 I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `UINavigationBar.appearance()`

Option 1:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(image, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Option 2:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "yourimage"), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

You can also add a titleView to the navigation item in your viewController.

Option 3:

```
navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "yourimage"))
```

Comment: I tried both solutions, and neither worked for me. Both simply displayed nothing in the navigation bar. The original code worked to get the image there, but didn't properly size it

Comment: I was able to use your code in the app delegate, but now I'm image is off center and over lapping the status bar. Is there a way to set the frame for the background image? Thanks!

Comment: not with .setBackgroundImage. You can in your view controller add an UIImageView to the navigationItem.titleView in your viewDidLoad

navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "yourImage"))

I have edited my answer.